# Rails - Using filter parameters in another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, filter

On my `index` page for one of my classes `item`, I have a form that filters entries in the database. You can filter by all fields that `item` has and all elements are represented so the code is as follows:

```
<%= form_tag(url_for({ :controller => :item, :action => :filter }), :id => 'filter_form') do %>
  <li>
    <% Category.active.each do |category| %>
      <% check_box_tag "categories[]", category.id, checked?(:categories, category.id) %>
      <%= category.name %>
    </li>
    ... 
<% end %>
```

And the controller in the `filter` method filters through all entries in Item using the query generated here:

```
@items = Item.includes(:category, ...)
             .joins(:item)
             .where(:category => params[:categories]
             ...
```

And so on for all fields in the filter.

I also have an `export` method in the same controller which exports all entries as a CSV file. The view renders what's in a helper method and passes the variable @items which is passed from the `export` method here as `Item.active`.

What I'd like is to have another method `export_filter` that, instead of exporting all entries in the `Item` table, exports just the filtered entries. In other words I'd like to get these form parameters for my filter form available in my `export_filter` method and use them to pass to the view and helper. How do I do this?

Comment: This question is a bit tricky to understand but, in an effort to re-write it, are you looking for away to get a list of all of the checked boxes in your form?

Comment: Nope, I'm trying to use the use the query that the parameters create to filter a table in another controller. However if @Swards' method works I won't need another controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is often handled by a single `index` method using formats (html or csv in your case).  The filtering is simply another scope on the list - the rendering is handled by a block within the method, something like:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.csv { render text: @products.to_csv }
end
```

As usual - Railscasts has covered this and is a great resource:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel?view=asciicast

To set the format - you could either do another button (and look at the value of the button) or another input that helps to select the format.

Comment: I added the format.csv line as you suggested and an extra button that changed the filter form's 'action' attribute as follows:
`form.attr("action", form.attr("action") + ".csv";`
`form.submit();`
`form.attr("action", form.attr("action").replace('\.csv',''));`
And then bound this to a new button within the same form